# What is my result in numbers?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential

The total resistance of two resistors connected in parallel is given by the formula:
$$\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_{1}} + \frac{1}{R_{2}}$$

What is the maximum possible error (absolute) if we have $R_{1} = 6 \pm 0.1\Omega$ and $R_{2} = 8 \pm 0.3\Omega$

(Hint: first write the formula in explicit form $R = \dots$ and calculate the total differential of this expression).

I use hint and I got to this formula
$$dR = \frac{R_{2}^2}{(R_{1}+R_{2})^2}dR_{1} + \frac{R_{1}^2}{(R_{1}+R_{2})^2}dR_{2}$$
I have a written solution and that is $0.088\Omega$ but I do not know what exactly I put into the given formula?

Comment: Its wrote in the brackets

Comment: Shouldn't it be as in Example 7: https://www.kharagpurcollege.ac.in/studyMaterial/6951Measurement%20and%20Error.pdf?

Comment: Since $R_2^2/(R_1+R_2)^2=R^2/R_1^2$ and $R_1^2/(R_1+R_2)^2=R^2/R_2^2,$ your formula is equivalent to the formula in Example 7 on the linked page. So then you follow the procedure there, being careful to use the numbers from your problem rather than the numbers in that example.